# Some memory management trouble: Error AddressSanitizer

Tags: c, memory, runtime-error, address-sanitizer

I was trying to solve LeetCode problem: [#14 Longest Common Prefix](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/). Here is the problem statement:

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings. If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

While solving it, I encountered some error. From the error message, I understand that there's invalid memory operations. However, still can't get points from the error messages:

```
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000110 at pc 0x55b10cc03190 bp 0x7fff30b617c0 sp 0x7fff30b617b0
READ of size 8 at 0x602000000110 thread T0
    #1 0x7f5a70bb00b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000111 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1-byte region [0x602000000110,0x602000000111)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f5a717f5bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #3 0x7f5a70bb00b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 07 fa fa fa 05 fa fa fa 07 fa fa fa 07 fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 04 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 04 fa fa fa 03 fa
=>0x0c047fff8020: fa fa[01]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==29==ABORTING
```

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *func(char ** strs, int strsSize){
    char *ans = strs[0];
    int n, i;

    for(i = 1;i < strsSize;i++){
        n = 0;
        while(1){
            if(ans[n] == strs[i][n]){
                n++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        ans[n] = '\0';
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
    printf("%s", func(s, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Does there anyone know where I got wrong?

Comment: *cant get points from the error messages.* What error messages? If you are asking about specific errors then please show them. For starters the strings in the `s` array are literals and are not writable. So `ans[n] = '\0';` is undefined behaviour as it tries to write to the literal.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. They will point you at the problem. If you're still having trouble, leave a comment and I'll help out more.

Comment: Sorry, I was not allowed to write much code content in this post. The error message is about heap buffer overflow. Or there’s a way can I provide the massive error message?

Comment: @scorerhsu I can see the edit with the error message. The code you posted has no heap allocation (malloc), so I'm puzzled. Does the code you posted exhibit the error?

Answer (score 3):

Compiler warnings will give a hint at the problem. Turning on compiler warnings is not simple, but here's what I find useful.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c11 -pedantic -g   -c -o test.o test.c
```

You can look up what those mean [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages) and [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html).

These give a series of warnings.

```
test.c:26:18: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [7]' discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
                 ^~~~~~~~
test.c:26:27: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [5]' discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
                          ^~~~~~
test.c:26:34: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [7]' discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
                                 ^~~~~~~~
```

What that tells us is we have a `const char []` that we're using as a `char *`. If we naively fix that...

```
const char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
```

Now there's a new warning.

```
test.c:27:23: warning: passing 'const char *[3]' to parameter of type 'char **' discards qualifiers
      in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    printf("%s", func(s, 3));
                      ^
test.c:4:20: note: passing argument to parameter 'strs' here
char *func(char ** strs, int strsSize){
                   ^
```

Again, we're using a `const char *[]` as a `char **`. Ok, let's naively fix that.

```
char *func(const char ** strs, int strsSize){
```

Another warning.

```
test.c:5:11: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char *' discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *ans = strs[0];
          ^     ~~~~~~~
```

Same problem, now we're using a `const char *` as a `char *`. Let's naively fix that.

```
const char *ans = strs[0];
```

Now we get an *error*.

```
test.c:18:16: error: read-only variable is not assignable
        ans[n] = '\0';
        ~~~~~~ ^
```

Finally there's the problem. `{"flower","flow","flight"}` are [string literals which are read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go). Those strings are in the executable itself and cannot be changed.

```
$ strings test
flower
flow
flight
```

When you assign them to a `char *` you're trying to modify them, but that's not possible. `ans[n] = '\0';` is undefined behavior and you get an error.

---

Those strings need to be writable. I don't know of an elegant way to do this, one way is to use `strdup` to copy the string literals into dynamic memory.

```
    char *s[] = {
        strdup("flower"),
        strdup("flow"),
        strdup("flight")
    };
```

Since they're dynamically allocated they need to be freed.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        free(s[i]);
    }
```